# Required minimum number of points on boundary of minimal surface

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

What is the minimum number of points required to uniquely determine a minimal surface in 3-Space? Four? Five?

If six or more points on boundary are given it gives rise to over-determination.. right?

Comment: Not without more hypotheses, no: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau's_problem

Comment: With five coplanar points $(0,1,0) , (\pm 1,0,0), \pm (0, \cosh t,t) $ a unit catenoid can be determined What hypothesis is involved here?

Comment: @Narasimham : Is that catenoid the only minimal surface passing through that 5 points?

Comment: Got it. Lot of wires through the 5 points when dipped in a soap solution produce a corresponding lot of soap films

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, exactly right, or put another way, (generalized) catenoids are far from the only minimal surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$.